# Rails console pry 'find' but not display the whole instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, pry

If I'm using pry in the console, is there any way to do a find, i.e., asdf = Asdf.find(1) without having it return the huge instance?   I just want to have asdf be that instance without seeing all the instance attributes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place semicolon`;` at the end of any expression to stop showing result of expression.

Here in your case `asdf = Asdf.find(1);`

Comment: This does something else though too - it doesn't make the instance stay current, seems to freeze it.   I brought up the instance like asdf = Asdf.find(1); and modified it via the website, but asdf didn't change.   So that is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I generally used a trick for this. But not at all recommended. Pry is build to show proper formatted response. However, you can have a go at it.

Instead of using this

```
asdf = Asdf.find(1)
```

You can append something to change the final output of your response like:

```
asdf = Asdf.find(1) and true
```

There you go, Now you'll have your value in asdf and what pry returns for above is simply 'true'.

Hope it helps

Comment: This also does not update the instance, keep it current.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to. But lets say you want to find asdf and see one attribute...you could do something like asdf=ASDF.find(1).username or whatever attribute you want to show up. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: well, I would still want asdf to be the instance, I just don't want to see the instance.   asdf = Asdf.find(1).do_not_display_it_just_allocate_it_to_asdf_without_spewing_out_all_the_attributes